# Counting how many words of different lengths are in the data so For example, (8,1) (words, length)

Tags: apache-pig

The function should output a  pair with the format  and with examples <”Length 8”, 1> or <”Length 7”, 1>, or similar such as <"8",1>.

To get the length of a string “theWord” in Pig you need to use the function SIZE for each word. To concatenate the size of an word with the string “Length “, you need to use the function CONCAT for each size. And lastly, I know that in order to convert an integer to string in order to concatenate it with another string cast it with (CHARARRAY). For example, I would use "(CHARARRAY)SIZE(word)".

I have code written but when I try to dump the data it does not do what I expect it to. I think I might need to do a count function, but I am a little stumped with this.

```
p1 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem1.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p2 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem2.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p3 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem3.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p4 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem4.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p5 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem5.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p6 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem6.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p = UNION p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6;
words = foreach p generate flatten(TOKENIZE(line , ' ,;:!?\t\n\r\f\\.\\-')) as word;
words_lower = foreach words generate LOWER(word) as word_lower;
words_unique = group words_lower by word_lower;
words_with_size = foreach words_unique generate SIZE(words_lower) as size, group;
words_with_size_concat = CONCAT words_with_count BY (CHARARRAY)size(words_lower) DESC, group;
```

Comment: As I've played with it, I do not need words_unique, but I need to add words_length = foreach words generate CONCAT('Length ', 
(CHARARRAY)SIZE(word)) as word_length;

Comment: You should use one load statement with a wildcard for file name like this p = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem*.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray); No union required.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The code should be as such:

```
p1 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem1.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p2 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem2.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p3 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem3.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p4 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem4.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p5 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem5.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p6 = LOAD 'poems/input/Poem6.txt' USING TextLoader AS(line:Chararray);
p = UNION p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6;
words = foreach p generate flatten(TOKENIZE(line , ' ,;:!?\t\n\r\f\\.\\-')) as word;
words_lower = foreach words generate LOWER(word) as word_lower;
words_length = foreach words generate CONCAT('Length ', (CHARARRAY)SIZE(word)) as word_length;
words_unique = group words_length by word_length 
words_with_count = foreach words_unique generate COUNT(words_length) as cnt, group;
words_with_count_sorted = ORDER words_with_count BY cnt DESC, group;
store words_with_count_sorted into 'poems/output/wordcount1';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code word_length should be modified.  It does not make sense to convert the words to the lower case without using them.  Consider...

```
words_length = foreach words_lower generate CONCAT('Length ', (CHARARRAY)SIZE(word)) as word_length;
```

In fact, the word length count can be applied directly to words without lowering them so the words_lower code may be removed.

On the words_unique, don't forget ';'